# How deactivate templates in AEM without modifying the users permissions

Tags: aem

Hi AEM Community I'm trying to deactivate some templates without making changes on the users permissions, I try with the allowedPaths property (for instance using a regex like this: /b/B) but I got an issue, if we copy and paste (on the same path) one page of one of the templates with the restriction on the allowedPaths property you can by-pass the restriction and you will be able to have pages on undesire paths. Any idea of what can I do to fix this? or something new to deactivate templates without modifying the users permissions?

Thanks in advance.

K.

Answer (score 0):

First. I'm assuming you are using the classic template system (not the newest ones, stored under /conf).

I do not recommend you to change your templates programmatically. These are stored in /apps so they are considered 'code' and not 'content'. Also  you'll loose any change if you reinstall your AEM packages.

Instead you can use the [cq:allowedTemplates property](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/the-basics/templates.html#Template%20Availability) directly in the root of the content tree of your site. You just need to set that property in any point of your content with the list of templates that should be available, any template not in that list wont be available for creating new pages.